# Hour in time not outputting correct

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

I am using Wanp as a testing server. Here is my code:

```
$dt = time();
$mysql_datetime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p %z" , $dt);
echo $mysql_datetime;
```

Here is the output:

```
2011-04-17 01:36:55 PM Eastern Standard Time
```

My problem is that, all the information is correct except or the hour, which is 4 hours ahead. The hour (`01` PM) is suppose to be (`09` AM). I have checked my date and time on my computer, and the time zone is correct.  What would cause this to happen, please help.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are this is due to the timezone being set incorrectly. (Although it's odd that the `%z` is correct, which I'm presuming it is.)

Have you tried calling [date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) with the appropriate [timezone value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your timezone correctly first before anything else.

Use `date_default_timezone_set`. [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) is list of supported timezones.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using the DateTime class (assuming you have a reasonably recent php)?

Something like:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s A e');
```

Alternatively if it still gets the timezone wrong, you could try to specify it:

```
$dt = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('EST'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s A e');
```

Anyway for more debugging information I'd recommend you look at `ini_get('date.timezone')` which, if incorrect, should be configured properly in your `php.ini` file.